# Incomplete definition of function- first order logic

Tags: logic, satisfiability, first-order-logic, propositional-logic, logical-validity

> Let $\Sigma=\{c,f^1,R_1^2,...,R_k^2\}$ where $c$ is constant, $f$ is one argument function, and $R_i$ are binary relations.
> Let $\Sigma_2=\{c',g^2,R_1'^1,...,R_k'^1\}$ where $c'$ is constant, $g$ is two argument function, and $R_i'$ are unary relations.
>
>  Show an algorithm that given a formula $\varphi$ above $\Sigma$, returns a new formula $\varphi'$ above $\Sigma_2$ such that: 
> $\varphi$ is satisfiable above $\Sigma$$\iff$ $\varphi'$ is satisfiable above $\Sigma_2$

Well I have a partial solution, goes as follow: 
Consider the next recursive definition: 
$c\rightarrow c'$ 
$f(t)\rightarrow g(t',t')$ 
$R_i(t_1,t_2)\rightarrow R_i'(g(t_1',t_2'))$

The problem with the definition is that it not complete: 
The function $g$ should have two roles:

1. defining the values of $f(t)$
2. Map elements of the form $(t_1,t_2)$ in a way that will allow $R_1'^1,...,R_k'^1$ to be consistent with $R_1^2,...,R_k^2$

I haven't found a way to define $g$, such that second requirement will be met.

Would appreciate help, hints will be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

First of all in your above 3 "recursive definitions" linking $\Sigma$ with $\Sigma_2$, clearly the function $g$ in $\Sigma_2$ doesn't have any role in defining the values of $f(t)$ in $\Sigma$, the values of $f(t)$ should be already defined in language $\Sigma$.

To check your 3 "recursive definitions" more deeply, it seems here the map from constant $c$ to constant $c'$ is critical since it completely determines your replacement of the argument $t'$ in function $g$. For example, in $\Sigma$ we only have one dimensional information such as coordinate $x$ of the real line. When we try to translate to $\Sigma_2$ where we may have two dimensional information such as 2-tuple coordinate $(x, y)$ in a plane, then the map from $c$ to $c'$ can be expressed as $m(c)=c \rightarrow (c, 0)$ via an ordered pair in the simplest case. So you may need to further clarify the map from $c$ to $c'$ in order to really find correct arguments for your function $g$ during the translation...